# PHPExcel - How to set text length of a cell?

Tags: laravel, phpexcel

How can I set text length of a cell so that after exporting file no one can exceed that length while editing that cell?

Comment: How would you set a fixed length for editing a cell in MS Excel?

Comment: @MarkBaker Excel provides a feature to allow user to enter only a limited number of characters in a cell. I want to implement same using PHPExcel.

Comment: The option probably doesn't exist in PHPExcel, because I had no idea that it existed in MS Excel..... I still have no idea how to do it in MS Excel, perhaps if you could provide a link to the MS Excel howto, then I could work it out

Comment: @MarkBaker I want to implement something like this https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/952-excel-cell-character-limit.html

Comment: Well you could check the [data validation rules](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) in PHPExcel which has a `TYPE_TEXTLENGTH` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could check the [data validation rules](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) in PHPExcel which has a `TYPE_TEXTLENGTH` option

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('A1')
    ->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_TEXTLENGTH );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_STOP );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Text exceeds maximum length');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Allowed input');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Maximum text length is 6 characters.');
$objValidation->setFormula1(6);
```

Comment: I am using http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs in laravel. Can this validation be implemented with this library?

Comment: The maatwebsite wrapper allows you to call PHPExcel methods directly if you need to, though I don't use it so can't tell you how to do so

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll rewrite my code with PHPExcel.